# Inheritable thread local in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-local

.NET 4.0 introduced [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class, which is great.  Now, my app use case requires something like Java's [`InheritableThreadLocal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/InheritableThreadLocal.html) class.  Is there anything like that in .NET?  If not, how can a new thread initializes its thread locals variables with those from the parent thread?  I suppose I need to make use the [initialization factory method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642263.aspx) but not sure what to put in there.

Comment: An interesting question; not really a direct answer, but *personally* I tend to avoid the scenario entirely by tying each thread instead to a context instance. I can then share the context instance between threads, or not; as I choose.

Comment: @Marc: I agree that is the preferred approach in most cases. However, in this case my code might call to library code which might (or might not) spawn threads calling back to my code.  So I'm not always in control of child thread creation.  I might be able to put a trap at every call-back entrance to check if it's a new thread to initialize its instance data, but that would be more awkward than the inheritable local thread storage approach.

Comment: fair enough; I just wanted to mention it in case you were missing a simpler option. Given the above comment, I suspect you are right - but I am not aware of something like `InheritableThreadLocal` in .NET, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is using [ILogicalThreadAffinitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.ilogicalthreadaffinative.aspx) and storing your object in the thread's CallContext with CallContext.SetData.

Object implementing ILogicalThreadAffinitive will flow across logical context switches, such as BeginInvoke and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.  Also note, this method is safer than using ThreadLocals for cases where you're using the thread pool because there's no way you can "strand" a thread local value on a thread and have another thread come and pick that up accidentally.

Comment: I looked at the documentation but not sure how I could use it to mimic the behavior of InheritableThreadLocal.  Can you elaborate your answer a bit more?